# Do broadcast receivers registered with an activity's context still respond if the activity goes into onStop?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If an activity registers a broadcast receiver, will it still be able to respond to the announcement if it has been put into the background (onStop())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers :

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

So I think it's the **onDestroy** method of the activity lifecycle that should be your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a registered broadcast receiver will always be able to receive a broadcast until you unregister it, or the application process gets killed by the system to reclaim memory.

So please remember to unregister when you don't need it anymore or else you could leave a potential memory leak.

It is advised to:

> Be mindful of where you register and unregister the receiver, for example, if you register a receiver in onCreate(Bundle) using the activity's context, you should unregister it in onDestroy() to prevent leaking the receiver out of the activity context. If you register a receiver in onResume(), you should unregister it in onPause() to prevent registering it multiple times (If you don't want to receive broadcasts when paused, and this can cut down on unnecessary system overhead).

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) for further reading